# SPIN: How to interact with this model checker passing parameter from outside?

Tags: spin, promela

I'm using SPIN Model Checker, I'd like to know If SPIN is a close box or not.
Can be used passing parameters from an upper level (ex: Phyton or batch?).
I'm interested on **Simulation mode** of SPIN, not on the Verification mode.

In the end, I'd like to know If (always in simulation mode) there is any method to write the simulation output to a phisical File, without using C embedded code.

Answer (score 0):

Been working with spin for years and haven't heard of any way to pass arguments into a promela program.

As far as the output, you can easily pipe the output of spin to a file, e.g. `spin model.pml > myfile.txt`